# MeowBottomNavigation issue - need to select menu from fragmentLoad() method in mainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using **MeowBottomNavigation** and from one fragment, I need to redirect to another fragment. but when I am doing that, the navbar displays the old menu selection.

Please help me.

This is on Home Fragment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC1vJ.png)

Now, its displaying data from 2nd fragment but nav shows HOME only. Ti should be 2nd nav.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7j4T.png)

### CODE

**getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment).commit();**

```
 bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav); 
    bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(1, R.drawable.ic_nav_home)); 
    bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(2, R.drawable.ic_baseline_category_24));
    
    bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.ShowListener(){ 
    @Override public void onShowItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) { 
       Fragment fragment = null; 
       switch (item.getId()){ 
         case 1: fragment = new HomeFragment(); break; 
         case 2: fragment = new CategoryFragment(); break; 
       } 
       fragmentLoad(fragment); 
   } 
    });
    
    
    bottomNavigation.show(1, true); 
    } 

public void fragmentLoad(Fragment fragment) {}
```

Comment: Here is the code that need to be updated

    public void fragmentLoad(Fragment fragment) {

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

Comment: MeowBottomNavigation Issue

Comment: Can you add more code for reference like how you have  init nav?

Comment: bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav);

 bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(1, R.drawable.ic_nav_home));
 bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(2, R.drawable.ic_baseline_category_24

Comment: bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.ShowListener(){
  @Override
  public void onShowItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {
   Fragment fragment = null;
   switch (item.getId()){
    case 1:
     fragment = new HomeFragment();
     break;
    case 2:
     fragment = new CategoryFragment();
     break;
   }
   fragmentLoad(fragment);
  }
 });

Comment: bottomNavigation.show(1, true);
}

public void fragmentLoad(Fragment fragment) {

Comment: Here i added more code in comment

Comment: You have to also call bottomNavigation.show(item.getId(), true);  before calling fragmentLoad method.